# run bash command when activating python virtualenv

Tags: linux, bash, virtualenv

currently I'm writing a bash script which can install a full searx-instance. To provide that, I must execute among others the following commands:

```
sudo -u searx -i
cd /usr/local/searx
virtualenv searx-ve
. ./searx-ve/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But, when I will execute this lines, they doesn't work because the bash enviroment change in the 1. and the 4. line.

I have written a bash command which can execute the first 4 commands, but the last command doesn't work, because I don't find out how to write a command via bash into the new enviroment, which is created by the following line:

```
. ./searx-ve/bin/activate
```

My current script:

```
sudo -u searx -i sh -c "cd /usr/local/searx;
virtualenv searx-ve;
 . ./searx-ve/bin/activate sh -c \"pip install -r requirements.txt\""
```

Comment: Sourcing `activate` just changes the values of some environment variables; it doesn't start a new shell. `sudo -u sears -i sh -c "cd /usr/local/searx; virtualenv sears-ve; . ./searx-ve/bin/activate; pip install -r requirements.txt"` should work.